# Prove $\mathbb{C}$ is the unique algebraic closure of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have already shown existence, but I have no idea how to do this because I am not allowed to use " For any collection of $P \subseteq F[x]$ of non-zero polynomials over a field $F$, a splitting field of $P$ over $F$ exists and is unique up to isomorphism of field extensions; that is, if $G_{1}$ and $G_{2}$ are two splitting fields of $P$ over $F$ then there exists a field isomorphism $\phi: G_{1} \to G_{2}$ with the following commutative diagram where $F \to G_{1}$ and $F \to G_{2}$ are the canonical embeddings:

> [image]

I am assuming we take another field to be the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{R}$ and arrive at some contradiction, but I'm at a loss

Comment: It's pretty easy to get a map from $\mathbb C$ to any algebraic closure of $\mathbb R$ (i.e. send $i$ to a square root of $-1$). A little work should show that anything outside of the image of this map is transcendental, meaning that this map has to be surjective, at which point you're basically done.

Comment: @MiloBrandt Thank you. I'm still a little confused You take a map $f:\mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $i$ is mapped to $\sqrt{-1}$ and consider a point $x$ not in $f(\mathbb{C})$ then $x$ is not of the form $a+b$\sqrt{-1}, a,b \in \mathbb{R}$...now how do I show that its not the solution of any polynomial with rational coefficients?

Comment: You would take the map to be $f:\mathbb C\rightarrow F$ where $F$ is the other algebraic closure. I haven't thought it through (hence am leaving a comment, not an answer), but you should be able to note that every polynomial over $\mathbb R$ splits over $\operatorname{im}  f$, which would mean that nothing outside of $\operatorname{im} f$ could satisfy any polynomial.

Comment: @MiloBrandt Awesome I got it.  Could you explain why $f$ being surjective implies $\mathbb{C} = F$?  Is it because its an isomorphism since its obviously onto and obvious $f(a+b) = f(a) + f(b)$?